# Get the top element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

*I've built advanced validation plugin which shows the errors in a specific way.*

However , when a user input is not valid , I *scroll* the page to the **first** element that has failed in validation.

this is how it [looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HE20.jpg) :

[image]

So where is the problem ?

I've bolded the `TD's` in black.

So you can see that `Currency textbox` is on the first TD where `Owner Name  textbox` is on the second TD

so `Currency textbox` has validated **first**  , and so , the page scroll to the Currency location and not to the OwnerName text box location . ( as I wish)

Question :

How can I find the topmost element ( lets assume that all failed elements has `.failed` class - just for simplicity).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just iterate through each of the elements:

```
var $failed = $('.failed');
var top = null;    // current "smallest" value
var found = null;  // current "topmost" element

$failed.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var cur = $this.offset().top;
    if (top === null || cur < top) {
        found = this;
        top = cur;
    }
});
```

Alternative, if you don't actually care which element it is, but just want the scroll position:

```
var tops = $failed.map(function() {
    return $(this).offset().top;
}).get();

var top = Math.min.apply(null, tops);
```

NB: code corrected to use `.offset` instead of `.scrollTop`

Comment: scrollTop when there's no scroll yields 0? ( i cant test , i'm out)

Comment: yeah, something like that - that's why I changed to `.offset()`

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in jQuery built in to give what you want. You would have to loop through all of the elements and use [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to see which one has the smallest top and left.

```
var failed = $(".failed");
var firstElem = failed.eq(0);
var firstPos = firstElem.offset();
failed.splice(0,1);
failed.each( function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    var pos = elem.offset();
    if (pos.top < firstPos.top || (pos.top===firstPos.top && pos.left<firstPos.left) {
        firstElem = elem;
        firstPos = pos;
    }    
});
```

Comment: ITYM `.offset()` rather than `.position()`

Comment: whoops, I did not have my morning coffee yet! Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var el;

$.each($(".failed"), function () {
    if (!el || el.offset().top > $(this).offset().top) {
        el = $(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sort` to sort by position:

```
var topElement = $('.invalid-elements')
    .sort(function(a, b) { return $(a).offset().top - $(b).offset().top })[0];
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QPfDr/)

Comment: @Alnitak: true that, and I've upvoted your answer, too. I thought it was a bit neat in terms of readability compared to the other approaches, but of course there is a tradeoff for performance. OP hopefully has an idea of the number of elements that will be involved and will be able to make an informed decision. I think both approaches should be put up there, but then again, so should your remark on performance impact :)